# How can I disable Lenovo Y700 shortcuts?

Tags: google-chrome, lenovo-laptop, backspace

Recently I bought Lenovo Ideapad Y700. I noticed that when I use chrome and want to go back in a tab using backspace it doesn't work and said that I need to use Alt + left key. How can I enable the backsapce key to work for this function?

Comment: Why do you think this is something specific to your Lenovo? What's telling you that you need to use Alt+Left instead?

Comment: Ahh looks like Chrome deprecated the use of backspace, so it's not you, it's Chrome.

Comment: I thought that its the computer cause I had another one that it worked the old way. Now after I upgraded chrome it changed. So it chrome fault and not Lenovo. Thanks.